# Enzyme/Jest Context API Injection (React) Not Working

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

So I want to test a component that uses React's context api and it's not working. It should be seemingly pretty simple - as stated here ([React js - How to mock Context when testing component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143925/react-js-how-to-mock-context-when-testing-component)) all you would have to do is something like this:

```
const context = { name: 'foo' };
const wrapper = mount(<SimpleComponent />, { context });
```

However, I have something very similar and it doesn't seem to be picking up on it.

Here is my test file -

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import Home from '../pages/home/index'
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

import stateVals from '../__mocks__/stateVals';

console.log('value of stateVals: ', stateVals)

describe('Pages', () => {
  describe('Index', () => {
    it('should render without throwing an error', function () {
      const wrap = mount(<Home/>, { stateData: { state: stateVals } })
      expect(wrap.find('div').text()).toBe('hello there main home')
    })
  })  
})
```

Here is my stateVals object I import:

```
const stateVals = {
  ContextNext: "ldjkfs",
  route: "/home",
  styledcomponent: "sfsdfsdfsdf",
  name: "dfasfasfasdf", 
  renderCloseAbout: false,
  aboutCardStatus: "closed",
  uploadedHistory: null, 
  greptchaTime: Date.now(), 
  loginStatus: "initial",
  registrationStatus: "N/A",
  userEmail: "N/A",
  completeRegistration: {}, 
  pageVal: "", 
  addPurchaseSubsJSON: ["empty"], 
  admins: ['SUPERDOOPERSECRET'],
  modal: {
    open: false, 
    message: ''
  }
}
export default stateVals
```

And here is the beginning of the component I want to test -

```
class Home extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <MainContext.Consumer>
      {stateData => {
        return(
          <div className='grid-container abspos'>
            {renderIf(stateData.state.modal.open==true)(
              <Modal/>
            )}
```

It throws this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

  26 |         return(
  27 |           <div className='grid-container abspos'>
> 28 |             {renderIf(stateData.state.modal.open==true)(
     |                                 ^
  29 |               <Modal/>
  30 |             )}
```

Why is this happening?

EDIT:

This also doesn't work:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import Home from '../pages/home/index'
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

import stateVals from '../__mocks__/stateVals';

console.log('value of stateVals: ', stateVals)
let context = {state: stateVals }
console.log('value of context: ', context)

describe('Pages', () => {
  describe('Index', () => {
    it('should render without throwing an error', function () {
      const wrap = mount(<Home/>,  context )
      expect(wrap.find('div').text()).toBe('hello there main home')
    })
  })  
})
```

Nor this;

```
  const wrap = mount(<Home/>,   {context: stateVals})
```

Nor using this:

```
  const wrap = mount(<Home/>,  {context: {stateData: stateVals}})
```

Nor this:

```
  const wrap = mount(<Home/>,  {context: {stateData: {state: stateVals}}})
```

Nor this;

```
const wrap = mount(<Home/>,  {stateData: stateVals})
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer turns out to be to wrap the provider as the context api hasn't been finalized yet. Thanks spenguin!

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import Home from '../pages/home/index'
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

import { Provider } from '../services/Context/Provider'

import stateVals from '../__mocks__/stateVals';

describe('Pages', () => {
  describe('Index', () => {
    it('test ', function () {
      const wrap = mount(<Provider value={{stateVals}}><Home/></Provider>)
      expect(wrap.find('#maintext').text()).toBe('hello there main home')
    })
  })  
})
```

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58867115/207981).

Comment: Can you share the Provider code so that we can understand easily.